# SQL Server query : UPDATE SET one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

Is there a way to execute the `SET IN` command in the query update ?

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET status IN (A, B, C) 
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

I did the syntax but an error appeared :

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.

Comment: No - one column can only hold **one value** (or `NULL`), you cannot set a single column to hold **multiple values** (this would violate even the **first normal form** of relational database design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want multiple updates based on id in single query

```
UPDATE table_a
    SET status = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN A
        WHEN 2 THEN B
        WHEN 3 THEN C
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

I guess this is your requirement, setting different status based on id

Answer (score 0):

you did mistake on set clause below is the correct sql

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET status='A'
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: can I set multiple value in status ?

Comment: @Ascaliko multiple value means?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
INSERT into table_a (id, status)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    status = VALUES(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case statement to update condition based value like "case when id=1 then 'A' WHEN ID=2 THEN 'B' and so on".
Ex.
update tab_a
set status=case when id=1 then 'A' WHEN id=2 then 'B' WHEN id=3 THEN 'C' end
where id in (1,2,3)

if you want to update the complete table with the default value for other than 1,2,3
then 
update tab_a
set status=case when id=1 then 'A' WHEN id=2 then 'B' WHEN id=3 THEN 'C' else 'Z' end